# Acumatica PR203000 in Extended Webservice - The system failed to commit the EmployeeAttributes row

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am experimenting with extending Acumatica’s web service endpoint to exposes objects from the PR module. I am using 2021R1 with the Sales Demo data. I have added a Top Level Entity with a PR203000 as the base. In addition to a few attributes on that top level entity, I have added a Detail Entity that maps to the TaxSettings tab on the screen. Specifically, in that detail entity, I have exposed the Description, State, and Value properties of the “Tax Settings” object. I then try and add data using the following PUT request:

```
    "EmployeeID": {
        "value": "KLM"
    },

    "TaxSettings": [
        {

            "State": {
                "value": "FED"
            },
            "Description": {
                "value": "Social Security Number"
            },
            "Value": {
                "value": "123-45-6789"
            }




        }
    ]
}
```

However, I receive the following error message:

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Operation failed",
    "exceptionType": "PX.Data.PXInvalidOperationException",
    "stackTrace": "..removed for brevity",
    "innerException": {
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "exceptionMessage": "The system failed to commit the EmployeeAttributes row.",
        "exceptionType": "PX.Data.PXException",
        "stackTrace": "   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.CommitChangesInt(Object itemToBypass, PXFilterRow[] targetConditions, PXFilterRow[] filtersForAction, SyImportRowResult importResult)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.CommitChanges(Object& itemToBypass, PXFilterRow[] targetConditions, PXFilterRow[] filtersForAction)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, being new to Acumatica development, I do not find this error sufficiently informative to pinpoint the issue. I have examined both the associated Graph and EmployeeAttributes DAC, but could not determine what might be causing the issue. While I realize the above JSON call does not contain all fields required in the DAC, to my understanding, the Graph calls “EmployeeAttributes.SetSettingNameForDescription” to populate these fields so I do not see this being the issue.

I am new to Acumatica, so any pointers as to how to troubleshoot would be much appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: The state field is read-only

Comment: @ChrisH thanks for the response. However, the `PREmployeePayrollSettingsMaint` graph enables the state field for import scenarios in the `_(Events.FieldSelecting<PREmployeeAttribute.description> e)`  method. Thanks.